# android: where are the image resources allocated?

Tags: android, image, resources

Is there anyway to get the actual images used in resources? e.g., I want the two png files in CheckBox in starstyle? Which directory does andorid keep them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it under \platforms\android-6\data\res\drawable-hdpi