# android: checkbox, radiobutton image resources

Tags: android, resources, widget

I am looking for the image resources that are used on my android device(s). I have one device running Froyo (Platform version 2.2.1, API Level 8, Samsung Galaxy tab) and one running Homeycomb_MR2 (Platform version 3.2, API level 13, Motorola Xoom). With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610522/android-where-are-the-image-resources-allocated) post I was able to locate image resources...

The problem is that for my Froyo device, the resources in "...platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-hdpi\ and ...\drawable-mdpi\" do not look like the check boxes or radio buttons I see on screen. Specifically, the widgets I see have a larger green fill circle in radio buttons and checks that extend outside the box for check boxes. Can anyone explain why I can't find the resource images I am seeing on screen? Are these widgets getting displayed using some other images?

Answer (score 1):

The resources that your see in your res folders are overridden by the system resources.

Let me give you an example :

The spinner will look differently on the emulator and that on your galaxy tab. As samsung has made changes in the Android os as per its requirement and overriden the controls for optimising its look

Comment: Any idea where I can find the "system resources" (i.e. their images) that Samsung overrode to create their tailored widget controls?